# How do I filter Service bus events with a Azure Function app?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

How do I filter Service bus events with an Azure Function app? If I have a "events" topic, and I publish 10 different events to the one topic. How do I get the azure Function to filter on the event. Does Azure Function apps service allow for filtering when using Function Apps?

Comment: Are you using Service Bus as input trigger binding or output binding. If input binding, you will already be using `subscription name`. if that's true then you can put the filter on subscription in service bus itself.

Comment: @user1672994 I am sorry your answer does not make sense to me. Yes it is an input binding. I am trying to subscribe to a specific event on a topic on the azure service bus. but you suggestion does not make sense to me.  " put the filter on subscription in service bus itself" is this in the portal? in the code of the function? Can you please clarify.

Comment: What @user1672994 says is correct. I've added some details in my answer. TLDR - use ASB to filter the messages, not Functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queues and subscriptions trigger azure Functions; they are not designed to filter out messages. If you have a topic that received two events, `EventA` and `EventB` and only one subscription that is triggering the Function, both event types will be handled by the function. It will be your function code responsibility to "filter" the messages and execute the correct logic. That filtering can be done by either looking at the customer headers (properties) or parsing the payload (body of the message).

Another approach is to have each message type received by a dedicated subscription on the Service Bus and have two functions, one per event type. That means creating two subscriptions in ServiceBus, one for `EventA` and another for `EventB` and then deploying two functions per event type. That way, you can have the logic of each function focus only on one event type and not have to "filter" anything out.

Another approach is to use a messaging middleware that can do it for you. That way you can have a single function to handle two or more message types but keep your code clean and with a single responsibility - handling a specific message type. You could use MassTransit or [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/azure-functions/service-bus) to accomplish that.

Comment: All the documentation on Azure Service Bus says it does Pub/Sub, and it uses Topics to do this. But I am yet to work on a useful pub / sub system that subscribes me to every type of message on the bus. Every subscriber gets every message.Either I have to have a seperate topic for each message / event type or When I filter it and find a message I am not interested in then I need to return it

Comment: Topics are used to publish. A single topic can contain multiple subscriptions. Each subscription acts as a queue to receive the messages from the topic. If you subscription rule is "catch all" then your receiver (in this case  a function) will get all the messages. If subscription has a filter (correlation or SQL) then the function per subscription Neill get filtered out messages. This has nothing to do with a function but rather the broker and how pub/sub is used. There are plenty of samples and documentation on ASB that shows it all.